# change Activity transition in AndroidManifest.xml use theme

Tags: android

In my `Activity` (called `MainActivity`), there is a button on the top of it, and others are `ListView` items.

When I click top button, I start a `LocationActivity`, and I want this `Activity` to be shown entering from bottom to top, and dismissed from top to bottom.

I set a Theme to `MainActivity` and `LocationActivity`, and it works but when I click `ListView` items  (in `MainActivity`) ,I start another `detailActivity`, and I just want this `detailActivity` show from right to left, and dismiss from left to right. But it can not dismiss from right to left,  it also from top to bottom.

This is my style I set to `MainActivity` and `LocationActivity`

```
<style name="ThemeLocationAct" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/LocationAnimTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="LocationAnimTheme" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
    <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/trans_in_down_up</item>
    <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/anim_nothing</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/anim_nothing</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/trans_out_up_down</item>
</style>
```

and this is I set to `DetailActivity`

```
  <style name="otherTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/anotherAnim</item>
</style>

<style name="anotherAnim" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
    <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/trans_in_right_left</item>
    <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/anim_nothing</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/anim_nothing</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/trans_out_left_right</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly, you can't do what you want within styles, but what you can do, is make transition programmatically, by using :

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.trans_in_right_left, 
                R.anim.trans_out_left_right);
```

after start your LocationActivity(meant `startActivity(new Intent(your_context, LocationActivity.class))`)

And use another anim files for your transition to `detailActivity`, like this:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.trans_in_left_right, 
                R.anim.trans_out_right_left);
```

And remove your style implementation for this